# Young man turned into cyborg to help defend city against monsters

Tags: story-identification, cyborg

The movie I'm trying to find the name for is a late 80's Sci-Fi action film that came out before *Revenge of the Nerds 2* - so 85-87. It was in theaters  during the summer.

In it there is this city that is under constant attack from a neighboring city or civilization of monsters. A young man volunteers to be turned into a cyborg to fight these monsters. He becomes a red and black leather covered cyborg able to change back and forth between human and cyborg.

Humans have been being captured and turned into slaves and mind controlled by a witch with an eye in the palm of her hand.  At one point the hero is thrown or jumps into a pit only to transform and catch himself with a grappling hook from his cyborg arm, then jumping back out to kick butt.

Can anyone identify this movie?

Comment: *"it was in theaters during the summer."*  Northern or southern (hemisphere)?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149413/70s-80s-movie-2-3-large-monsters-terrorise-asian-population

Answer (score 5):

There is a very similar question [here](http://www.badmovies.org/forum/index.php?topic=124488.0;wap2) where the answer seems to be *[Infra-man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073168/)* although it was released in 1975.

> I agree with Andrew, that really does sound like Infra-Man, the character She-Demon has eyes in the palms of her clawed hands, and they do brainwash some of the good guys. Great costumed/kaiju flick with all the elements that make this genre so fun to watch. Despite losing the widescreen format of the recent DVD release "The Super Inframan", the VHS "Infra-Man" version has some of the most hilariously enthusiastic dubbing I've ever heard. All the mutants have great over the top voices, and who could ever forget a villainess like Princess Dragon Mom.
>
> Its possible this could have been shown in some theaters as a revival in '87, but the original was definitely put out in 1975.

[image]

There's nothing specific in the trailer that matches, but does this look what you're looking for?

One possibility is that you were watching a 1987 episode of Siskel and Ebert's *Guilty Pleasures*. [They did mention Infra-Man in that year](http://siskelandebert.org/video/27RDMKKD5987/Guilty-Pleasures-1987).