# 70s/80s movie - 2/3 large monsters terrorise Asian population

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching an old sci-fi movie as a kid, but I can't recall too many details, unfortunately.

It seemed to be sort a knock-off of a Godzilla movie. There were two or three large monsters that were terrorizing the Asian population.

I remember one scene in particular where a large, green walking monster with tentacles, picked up a man in a white jumpsuit and hard hat and smashed him into some power lines (he worked at a power plant).
There were also one or two other different type of monsters causing the same type of damage.

If I had to guess, it was made in the 70s or 80s.

Does anyone know this movie? Given my poor description.

Comment: Can you describe the other monsters at all? Was there a "good" monster that saved the day? Was the film in english or was the English dubbed on top of the originally recorded language? Did you see it on tv or at a movie theater? More details the better.

Comment: I don't recall a "good" monster per day. I think another monster was pink or orange with a round sort of bug like body. It was a vhs rental, but I think it was a bit newer than the movie suggested below. Yog. I feel like the electricity plant played a bigger role as a setting in the script.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it was [The Super Inframan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073168/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), a 1975 Hong Kong sci-fi action movie that has a cybernetically enhanced man fighting a group of monsters from within the earth, including a woman with laser-shooting eyeballs in her palms, skeleton ghosts, a demon princess, and a plant-human-hybrid monster that sprouts enormous tentacles at some point.

It features a scene with the tentacled plant monster [electrocuting a jumpsuited guy by smashing him into some panels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hk6yE3QcIE4?t=23m30s) (23m30s).

Comment: This is it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bry Glad you found the movie! Please tick the green check beside waldrumpus's answer to indicate it answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you saw [Yog: Monster from Outer Space (aka Space Amoeba)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Amoeba). Released in the US in 1971, it features three monsterous creatures, including a green one with tentacles, terrorizing a Pacific island resort community.

> The film tells the story of extraterrestrial amoeba-like aliens that highjack a probe and, after crash landing on a small South pacific atoll, create gigantic monsters from native lifeforms (a Kisslip cuttlefish, stone crab and Matamata turtle) with plans of conquering the Earth.

[Theatrical poster](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/fe/Space_Amoeba_1970.jpg/220px-Space_Amoeba_1970.jpg)

You may have seen the English dub, or the original Japanese.

[Trailer showing man being grasped and tossed](https://youtu.be/CwLpKCu_JQ8)